# error error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'char' in initializer list

Tags: c++

I am not used to work with c++, ;)

I get the follwoing error when compiling my code on this line :

```
#define NUM 34
char tmp[4] = {(xorValue&0xffff) % NUM, 0, (xorValue>>16) % NUM, 0};
```

Errors :

On **(xorValue>>16) % NUM**

```
 error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'char' in initializer list

insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `xorValue`?

Comment: I feel that the error is relatively clear. Your `(xorValue&0xffff) % NUM` is `unsigned long` (presumably `xorValue` is `unsigned long`)  and you're using it to initialize a `char`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `const` in preference to `#define` for constants.

Comment: xorValue = value[32] << 24 value is unsigned char array

Comment: char tmp[4] = {(char)((xorValue&0xffff)) % NUM, 0, (char)((xorValue>>16) % NUM), 0}; working, thank you all

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include additional details. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Yksisarvinen , i copied the error that i get, it works now, if you can add any additional details, you're welcome